# Cannot cast System.Web.Http.WebHost.Routing.HostedHttpRoute to System.Web.Http.Routing.IHttpRoute

Tags: c#, casting, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

After updating ASP.NET Web API to 2.2 (from nuget package version 4.0 to 5.2) for a Web API solution, I can no longer cast an object of type `System.Web.Http.WebHost.Routing.HostedHttpRoute` to `System.Web.Http.Routing.IHttpRoute`.

According to this [source](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http.WebHost/Routing/HostedHttpRoute.cs) of `HostedHttpRoute`, it implements `IHttpRoute` so the cast should work. However, this source must be outdated for 5.2...?

Does anyone know if `HostedHttpRoute` has changed in any way that would cause this issue? If so, please share any information you have about such changes.

If you're wondering why I'm trying to perform this cast - it's part of retrieving all the routes of a web API application and return an `HttpRouteCollection`. This involves calling the `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes()` method in to retrieve a `RouteCollection` object. Each item in this `RouteCollection` object is a `HttpWebRoute` object, which contains a property named `HttpRoute` of type `HostedHttpRoute`. Each of these `HostedHttpRoute` would be cast to an `IHttpRoute` which is then added to a `HttpRouteCollection`.

Comment: What is WebAPi 4.0 to 5.2? WebAPI's newest version is 2.2 AFAIA

Comment: The name of the API nuget package says 2.2. However, if you look at the actual version number, it's 5.2.2 (or 5.2.3 which was released last week).

Comment: I've updated my question to clarify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3The issue was that the application where this casting code is written had API v5.2.3 installed, where the API web application had API v5.2.2 installed, so the IHttpRoute type had a mismatch version problem. For some reason, 5.2.3 works with 4.0, but not 5.2.2. I updated the web app to 5.2.3 and the issue is resolved.